# Leaflet function to track point coords on map move

Tags: leaflet

New to the forum. I also posted this question on Stackoverflow, not sure it is the same forum.

I am trying to build a Vt of 360 degree panopictures with OSM map using Leaflet.

I would need a function which, given the LatLng coord of a point, returns the pixel coordinates x, y of that point  relative to the origin pixel (to the top left corner of the map container) when moving (i.e panning/dragging) the map and when zooming the map. For example: when the map does not move, x=30, when panning the map x changes following the actual map move accordingly.

Comment: Sometimes documentation can be helpful. See `latLngToLayerPoint(<LatLng> latlng)` method in https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map

Comment: I tried that function but it returns x, y coords of a LatLng point at a fixed view, i.e. when panning the map the x, y values remain the same. I would need a function which returns x, y coord of the point as the map moves.

Comment: Did you read x,y coordinates within event function for map `move` event?

Comment: I used the function with map.on 'move' event then I "pass" x, y values to layer in the xml file generated by the Krpano viewer but id does not works i.e. the spot remain in the same position moving the map. When I use map.latLngToContainerPoint() and map.on 'move' instead, it works: I cannot figure it out why....

Comment: You are right, it looks like I should adhere to my own advice of reading documentation carefully. `latLngToLayerPoint` method gives pixel coordinates relative to layer origin pixel (and this of course does not change). `latLngToContainerPoint` method gives pixel oordinates relative to map container, which does change when map is panned.